# Ways to Count a Printer With a Built in Scanner as a Scanner for WIA

Tags: c#, scanning, wia

I am currently working with some OMR software that will take and scan sheets from a scanner, and then write their information to a text file. For getting available local scanners, I am using [WIA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wia/-wia-startpage); to get these scanners, I would use some bit of code like

```
public List<ScannerInfo> GetWiaDevices()
{
    WIA.DeviceManager mgr = new WIA.DeviceManager();
    List<ScannerInfo> retVal = new List<ScannerInfo>();

    foreach (WIA.DeviceInfo info in mgr.DeviceInfos)
    {

        if (info.Type == WIA.WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType)
        {
            foreach (WIA.Property p in info.Properties)
            {

                if (p.Name == "Name")
                    retVal.Add(new ScannerInfo(((WIA.IProperty)p).get_Value().ToString(), info.DeviceID));
            }

        }

    }
    return retVal;

}
```

Now, I am working with something that is technically a printer (and that Windows reads as a printer) -- the [Konica Minolta Bizhub 282](https://copier1.com/product/konica-minolta-bizhub-282/?gclid=CjwKCAiA9JbwBRAAEiwAnWa4QyWrOfxgeL1dRuEq0PDOn0Fw6ZSkm06Oo_HHctIAqhM6XRsMbkKBshoCOHEQAvD_BwE), I believe. Unfortunately, `if (info.Type == WIA.WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType)` doesn't recognize printers with built in scanners *as* scanners, so when I run this code checking for local scanners, the printer doesn't show up.

Is there a way to make printers with built-in scanners show up on the list, and furthermore, to make them usable as scanners in C#?   Thanks for your time!

Comment: Maybe you can look at the code in [GetDevices](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/WIA/DeviceManager/-/php-devicemanager-class-examples.html#0x5c0b69cf66c0fa307c791f7de74d9d7fca22c936f38c93427d51f71e89a52ce5-252,,272,).

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT Thank you; that's a good idea!

Comment: Printers with built in scanners are technically TWO devices and require TWO drivers, not one.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas oh wow, that's good to know! Do you have any idea how I might get both drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like this printer has a scanner that will show up as a twain or WIA source.

There certainly are no drivers on the Minolta site for it (only PCLx and PostScript Print Drivers).

The way this scanner works is to use a SMB network share setup by your IT admin.  The printer will dump scanned documents there after it is configured properly.

You can read about it  [here](https://www.konicaminolta.com.au/KonicaMinolta/media/KonicaMinolta/Manuals/Win2008_SMBv2.pdf) .

If I somehow missed something.. (I don't think I did), ALL of the manuals for that printer are  [here](https://www.konicaminolta.com.au/support/technical-support/user-manuals-safety-information)